# Downloading WS02 Developer Studio

Tags: wso2-esb

Sorry for the basic question here but how do I download WS02 Developer Studio - I'd like to try out the ESB and compare it with Mulesoft's ESB product which I use on a regular basis. So far I haven't been able to even download it either directly or from Eclipse Market place - hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can download from [1] or [2].

[1] http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/

[2] http://wso2.com/more-downloads/developer-studio